# Unable to run ILAsm using ProcessInfo

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il, ilasm

I'm trying to compile IL code using bat file and C#. Here is a C# code

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ILCompiler, @"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\" + ILCompiler + 
    " "+OutILFile+" /exe /output:" + OutExeFile + " /debug=IMPL");
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
using (Process.Start(processStartInfo)) ;
```

Here is a bat file

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe Source.il /exe /output:my-assebmly.exe /debug=IMPL
pause
```

The strings for running ILAsm are **exactly the same** (that is, `processStartInfo.Arguments = Arguments = "c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\ilasm.exe Source.il /exe /output:my-assebmly.exe /debug=IMPL")`

In spite of it, I get an error when I run using C#

> The program can't start because fusion.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

How do I fix it ? I need to run ILAsm using C#.

Comment: No, I mean ILAsm. I need to compile *.il file to *.exe.

Comment: Is this simply that the working path wasn't set? Try setting the working path to the folder ilasm is in

Comment: try setting the `processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"`

Comment: @Nacereddine, it seems like it's working now. That's fantastic.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"
```

Comment: However, now it's saying that it can't find *.il to compile. This is because of working directory.

Comment: Yes. use the full path for the `.il`.